# Replace a given substring before the digits

Tags: regex, replace

In a string like /p20 (can be any number) i want to replace the /p into /pag- but keep the number /pag-20

This is what i tried:

```
preg_replace('/\/p+[0-9]/', '/pag-', $string);
```

but the result is /pag-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capturing group and a backreference:

```
$string = "/p-20";
echo preg_replace('~/p-([0-9])~', '/pag-$1', $string);
                       ^^^^^^^          ^^
```

Here, `/p-` matches a literal substring and `([0-9])` matches and *captures* any 1 digit  into Group 1 that can be referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern.

Alternatively, you may use a lookahead based solution:

```
preg_replace('~/p-(?=[0-9])~', '/pag-', $string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/utRuXJ)

Here, no backreference is necessary as the `(?=[0-9])` positive lookahead does not consume text it matches, i.e. it does not add the text to the match value.